# How to write an R function which assigns to the object of the calling environment?

Tags: r, function, global-variables, subset, assignment-operator

I have a objects of certain class which contain several matrices, and I would like to build a function which access and possibly modifies subset of such matrix. For example:

```
foo<-list(x=diag(1:4),y=matrix(1:8,2,4))
class(foo)<-"bar"
attr(foo,"m")<-4
attr(foo,"p")<-2
rownames(foo$x)<-colnames(foo$x)<-colnames(foo$y)<-c("a.1","b.1","b.2","c.1")
attr(foo,"types")<-c("a","b","b","c")
```

Now I could access and modify certain elements like this:

```
foo$x[attr(foo,"types")%in%c("c","b"),attr(foo,"types")%in%c("c","b")]    
foo$x[attr(foo,"types")%in%c("c","b"),attr(foo,"types")%in%c("c","b")]<-matrix(5,3,3)
```

But instead of the above, I would like to construct a following type of function:

```
modify<-function(object,element,types){
  # check that the object is proper class, 
  # and the element and the types are found in the object

  # this returns to the local copy of the corresponding subset:
   object[[element]][attr(object,"types")%in%types,attr(object,"types")%in%types]     
}
```

For accessing the above function is ok, but what if I want to modify the original object? Obviously this doesn't work:

```
modify(foo,"x",c("c","b"))<-matrix(5,3,3)
Error in modify(foo, "x", c("c", "b")) <- matrix(5, 3, 3) : 
  could not find function "modify<-
```

Is it possible to get that work somehow? If not, one option I could think of is adding argument `replace.with` to function `modify` and then making the assignment first to the local copy and then copying the change to the object in the calling environment using `assign` function. For this I would need to find the original object in the calling environment, but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found a solution myself with a help of old post from [R-help by Brian Ripley:](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Making-a-Subset-Assignment-function-quot-lt-quot-td4634717.html)

```
foo<-list(x=diag(1:4),y=matrix(1:8,2,4))
class(foo)<-"bar"
attr(foo,"m")<-4
attr(foo,"p")<-2
rownames(foo$x)<-colnames(foo$x)<-colnames(foo$y)<-c("a.1","b.1","b.2","c.1")
attr(foo,"types")<-c("a","b","b","c")

`modify<-` <- function(x, element, subset,value) UseMethod("modify<-")
`modify<-.bar` <- function(x, element, subset,value) { 

  x[[element]][,attr(foo,"types")%in%subset] <- value
  x }

modify(foo,"x",c("c","b"))<-matrix(5,3,3)
foo$x
    a.1 b.1 b.2 c.1
a.1   1   0   0   0
b.1   0   5   5   5
b.2   0   5   5   5
c.1   0   5   5   5
```

Answer (score 1):

With the caveat that this is generally frowned upon, you can use the following:

From the target environment, set a variable to the environment and then pass that as an argument to your function which you can use in `assign`, `get` etc

```
en <- environment()
myfunc <- function(..., en=en) {
  . etc .
  assign("varname", envir=en)
}
```

Note that if you are simply changing attributes, the `setattr` function of the data.table package already implements this quote nicely:

```
 setattr(x,name,value)
```

Comment: If you're just changing attributes, the built-in `attr<-` does fine, and modifies in place. I'm not sure what advantages `setattr` has.

Comment: Thanks, but the problem with this is that the name of the original object i.e. "varname" can be arbitary.

Comment: @Hemmo, how is that a problem?  Use an unquoted variable in `assign`

Comment: If I have a object in calling environment called myvar, and I run function myfunc(var,en), function myfunc doesn't know that the I need to assign something to the variable named myvar. But it doesn't really matter, I found another solution, which I will post shortly.